the debugger wont attach to my vscode program since started using adb wifi(works with usb,but cannot use usb anymore)
im building a flutter android app,and since i started using adb thorugh wifi,every time i try to run the program through wifi on my mobile devices(using 2 phones),i get this error
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:54175/Aw6iOimWGZI=/
i did not get this error when i used usb's to connect between the computer and phones,only started since using adb,but i cannot go back to usb-can anyone help?
im using the vscode adb interface extension for the adb management,and my devices ip is different than the one stated in the error,any help would very much appreciated,thanks in advance.
i have tried restarting the adb connection multiple times and tried to change the launch.json to attach instead of running,both didnt work.
(only using the main launch,so didnt change it on profile and release mode)
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

    
        {
            "name": "AwShare_SchoolProject",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "AwShare_SchoolProject (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "AwShare_SchoolProject (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        }
    ]
}

